# Parsing RapidJSON string returns NULL on brackets

Tags: c++, rapidjson

```json
{"1":"value","data":[A,B,C]}
```

`1` returns `value`.

`data` returns `null`.

Adding quotations `"[A,B,C]"` isn't an array anymore.

```
rapidjson::Value &arr = document["data"];
if( !arr.IsArray() || arr.Size() != 3 )
{
    Return;
}
else
{
    x = arr[rapidjson::SizeType(0)].GetDouble();
    y = arr[rapidjson::SizeType(1)].GetDouble();
    z = arr[rapidjson::SizeType(2)].GetDouble();
};
```

How should I properly handle the [bracketed array]?

I have quite a lot of objects without quotes. Can I handle the objects without quotes?

Comment: This doesn't look like C, it looks like C++.

Comment: `Return` should be `return` -- C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure the values in the array are doubles?

Comment: The project is supposed to be C++, Though 2/3 of C++ with includes shows  errors, therefore I've been opening/writing/closing files the hard way in C.

Comment: Can you show the exact json you're handing in, rather than using the meta-values `A` `B` and `C`.  Taken in isolation, that's not valid json.

Comment: Example:[-56.0134,472.802,14494.1] I believe decimal are a double. I haven't found other questions on this use case, I'm learning so I don't know all the proper terms. https://pastebin.com/zW0iWANu

Comment: OK.  That looks good, thanks.  You can always verify the json itself is good on a site like jsonlint.org.

Comment: Does the `rapidjson::Value` object have a stream-insertion operator?  That might give some insight into what kind of thing it got parsed as.  I.e., `std::cout << arr << std::endl;`

Comment: Not sure what's going on.  Your code is a very close match for the example shown on the [rapidjson tutorial page](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html).  Meaning it ought to work.  About all I can think is to fire this up in a debugger, and single step through to try and get a read as to where it's failing.  Since rapidjson is a header-only library, it has the advantage of making debugging trivial.

Comment: Thanks for all the great input, I'd be back to the drawing board if jsonlint.org didn't like my JSON, I used some of the tutorial to emphasize my issue. https://pastebin.com/x2Bctmdb  
Ignore the messiness of this code it's very much a WIP.

Comment: Is this a direct copy/paste of the real JSON?  Or, is it possible that the real JSON is using `{}` instead of `[]` for the `x,y,z` values? `"data":{A,B,C}` *might* make more sense than `"data":[A,B,C]` for fixed-length groups of values, depending on which way the JSON designer decided to go. What does `arr.GetType()` return? Sounds like it is not returning `kArrayType`, does it really return `kNullType`?

Comment: "pos" I thought was returning empty for value [-56.0134,472.802,14494.1] but the code is "document["pos"].GetString()" though it is passing as an array, and size of 3.
"pos" returns [-56.0134,472.802,14494.1] for value "[-56.0134,472.802,14494.1]" though this is not an array of size 3.
assuming the data is written correctly the values will always be 6 digits separated by a decimal according to double, using the tutorial code the 3 values return wildly different from the given values..a[0] = 536870912,
a[1] = 0,
a[2] = -1073741824,
x = (null),
y = (null),
z = (null)